# How to fill in automatically model data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-ajax

I have a login model with username and password and code.

And Now I want if you fill in the code then automatically the associated  username and password has to been filled in. So for example you fill in for code: HD and then TAB and then the textfields for username and password has to been filled in.

The action method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoginBalieUser(V_LoginModel_BalieUser model)
        {

            ISalesPersonProfile salesAgent99 = CommerceFrameworkBase.SalesPersons.GetSalesPerson("HD");           
            var salesAgent = CommerceFramework.ShopAccounts.GetShopAccount(Guid.Parse("3E90BB13-36BA-435D-8ED7-E930A4F8C758"), true);           

            if (model.BalieCode == salesAgent99.Id)
            {
                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                        return View(model);

                if (!ShopApi.UserState.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("","The username or password is incorrect" );
                    return View(model);
                }

            }



            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile");
        }
```

The extended model looks like this:

```
public class V_LoginModel_BalieUser : LoginModel
    {

        public string BalieCode { get; set; }
}
```

and the original model looks like this:

```
 //
    // Summary:
    //     A model to login into the webshop.
    public class LoginModel
    {
        public LoginModel();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the password.
        [AllowHtml]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_RequiredField")]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_MaxLengthExceeded")]
        public virtual System.String Password { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether to remember the user to login him automatically
        //     on the next visit.
        [Display(Name = "Login_RememberMe")]
        public virtual System.Boolean RememberMe { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the username.
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_InvalidField")]
        [Display(Name = "EmailAddress")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_RequiredField")]
        [StringLength(80, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_MaxLengthExceeded")]
        [TrimAttribute(new[] { })]
        public virtual System.String UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

and the view looks like this:

```
@{

    Layout = LayoutPaths.General;
}

@model Sana.Commerce.DomainModel.Account.V_LoginModel_BalieUser


<div class="semicolumn">
    <div class="form-holder">
        @using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.BalieCode)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.BalieCode)
                    </td>

                </tr>



                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.UserName)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.UserName)
                    </td>

                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.Password)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Password)
                    </td>

                </tr>


            </table>
            <div class="form-row">
                <h4></h4>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>


        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Id").change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: '@Url.Action("loginbalieUser", "profile")',
                    data: { id: $("").val() },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#UserName").val(data[0]);
                        $("#Password").val(data[1]);
                    }
                });
            })


        });
    </script>     

    }
```

So I tried with a Ajax call. But the exact implementation I don't know.

Thank you

this is the model of: ISalesPersonProfile

```
//
    // Summary:
    //     Interface for the Sales Person Profile entity.
    public interface ISalesPersonProfile : IEntity
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Email of this Sales person.
        string Email { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Sales person's code.
        string Id { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Job Title of the Sales person.
        string JobTitle { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Name of the Sales person.
        string Name { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Phone number of the Sales person.
        string Phone { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the related customer id list related with the sales person.
        IList<string> RelatedCustomerIds { get; set; }
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
loginbalieUser:232 Uncaught ReferenceError: ValidateBalieCode is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (loginbalieUser:232) on this line:  <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.BalieCode, new { @onchange = "ValidateBalieCode()" })
                    </td>

                </tr>
```

and this is my ajax call:

```
function ValidateBalieCode(){
                var code =  $('input#BalieCode').val();

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: '@Url.Action("ValidateBalieCode", "profile")',
                    data: { "BalieCode":code },
                    success: function (data) {

                        $("input#UserName").val(data.UserName);
                        $("input#Password").val(data.Password);
                    }
                });


            }
```

if I load the page in Goog chrome:

I see this:

```
  function ValidateBalieCode(){
                var code =  $('input#BalieCode').val();

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: '/sitemap.xml',
                    data: { "BalieCode":code },
                    success: function (data) {

                        $("input#UserName").val(data.UserName);
                        $("input#Password").val(data.Password);
                    }
                });


            }
```

oke,

I have it now like this:

```
  function ValidateBalieCode() {
                var code = $('input#BalieCode').val();

                $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    type: "Get",
                    url: "/profile/ValidateBalieCode/",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { "BalieCode": code },
                    success: function (data) {

                        $("input#UserName").val(data.UserName);
                        $("input#Password").val(data.Password);
                    }
                });


            }
```

but the url is like this:

```
http://localhost:5923/en-us/profile/loginbalieuser
```

so always: en-us. but if I do this:

```
 url: "en-us/profile/ValidateBalieCode/",
```

then in chrome I see this:

```
http://localhost:5923/en-us/profile/en-us/profile/ValidateBalieCode/?BalieCode=1 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I could not find any control with id `#Id`. So what is `$("#Id").change`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edit the post I thought Id is the id of salesAgent99. I don't know exactly how to do it with Ajax

Comment: It is really hard to understand your question. Your `LoginBalieUser` action is marked with `HttpPost` and in your ajax you specify `get`..

Comment: post is if the user wants to login. But first a code has to been filled in in the baliecode textfied. If a baliecode has found(stored in the database) then the textfield username and textfield password are filled in. Then the user will press on the login button and logs in.

Comment: Oke. I put a more clear question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343272/how-to-return-data-from-model-in-textfields-with-ajax-call

Comment: I am about to an answer to your question.

Comment: Oke, Will be nice. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return data from model in textfields with Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343272/how-to-return-data-from-model-in-textfields-with-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separate action method for getting `UserName` and `Password` against `BalieCode`.

---

**[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yJLHqa)**

---

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginBalieUser", "LogIn", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.BalieCode)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.BalieCode, new { @onchange = "ValidateBalieCode()" })
                    </td>

                </tr>



                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.UserName)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.UserName)
                    </td>

                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.Password)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(modelItem => modelItem.Password)
                    </td>

                </tr>


            </table>
            <div class="form-row">
                <h4></h4>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new SampleViewModel());
    }


    public JsonResult ValidateBalieCode(string BalieCode)
    {
        string strUserName = string.Empty;
        string strPassword = string.Empty;

         List<SampleViewModel> _db = new List<SampleViewModel>();           
        _db.Add(new SampleViewModel() { BalieCode = "1", UserName = "test1", Password = "test1" });
        _db.Add(new SampleViewModel() { BalieCode = "2", UserName = "Test2", Password = "test2" });


        var SampleViewModel = _db.Find(x => x.BalieCode == BalieCode);
        if(SampleViewModel != null)
        {
            strUserName = SampleViewModel.UserName;
            strPassword = SampleViewModel.Password;
        }

        return Json(new{ UserName = strUserName, Password = strPassword }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function ValidateBalieCode(){
                var code =  $('input#BalieCode').val();

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: '@Url.Action("ValidateBalieCode", "Home")',
                    data: { "BalieCode":code },
                    success: function (data) {

                        $("input#UserName").val(data.UserName);
                        $("input#Password").val(data.Password);
                    }
                });


            }

        </script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Very nice. But ofcourse I have the data in a database stored

Comment: Yes, for demo I used a List. For actual scenario, you need to find UserName and Password against BalieCode from your database.

Comment: loginbalieUser:232 Uncaught ReferenceError: ValidateBalieCode is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (loginbalieUser:232) on this line:  <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.BalieCode, new { @onchange = "ValidateBalieCode()" })
                    </td>

                </tr>

Comment: `ValidateBalieCode` is in script tags and make sure that jQuery is loaded properly?

Comment: Yes, I put the code outside the Document.ready(fucntion). But now it is rearching for a site.xml doc?? jquery.js:9175 GET http://localhost:5923/sitemap.xml?BalieCode=1 404 (File not found)
send @ jquery.js:9175
ajax @ jquery.js:8656
ValidateBalieCode @ loginbalieUser:490
onchange @ loginbalieUser:232

Comment: But I don't have sitemap.xml